# Check Table Exist Before Create Table On FluentMigrator

Tags: c#, .net, migration, fluent-migrator

I'm looking for a way to write a extension method for fluent migrator check before create table, something like this

```
Schema.TableIfNotExist("table").InSchema("dbo").WithColumn("Id").AsInt32().NotNullable()
```

is it possible to write a extension method ?

Comment: Have you tried using an try catch block? Or wrap the create table as am extension method with the try catch block inside the method.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you can

```
public static class Ex
{
    public static IFluentSyntax CreateTableIfNotExists(this MigrationBase self, string tableName, Func<ICreateTableWithColumnOrSchemaOrDescriptionSyntax, IFluentSyntax> constructTableFunction, string schemaName = "dbo")
    {
        if (!self.Schema.Schema(schemaName).Table(tableName).Exists())
        {
            return constructTableFunction(self.Create.Table(tableName));
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }       
    }
}
```

You are going to have two caveats (that I know of):

1. If you call the function in the same migration more than once, the first one will
   succeed, the others would fail, since the exists check requires the
   schema context to be updated with the new tables, which
   doesn't happen until the next migration (or until the current migration successfully executes).
2. If you use [AutoReversingMigrations](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki/Auto-Reversing-Migrations), the expression won't be
   automatically mapped to its coresponding down statments. Meaning
   that the implicit down won't have any effect.

---

To use toe above extension and your example, you would do

```
public override void Up()
{
    this.CreateTableIfNotExists("table", table => table.WithColumn("Id").AsInt32().NotNullable());
}
```

Comment: This also works for columns. You can define the function as such `public static IFluentSyntax CreateColumnIfNotExists(this MigrationBase self, string table, string column, 
            Func<ICreateColumnOnTableSyntax, IFluentSyntax> columnCreator, string schema = "dbo")` and then use it like this: `this.CreateColumnIfNotExists("Foo", "Bar", column => column.OnTable("Foo").AsDecimal());`. There may be a better way to do this that doesn't involve duplicating the table declaration, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @MorganThrapp You would do something like this perhaps:  `public static IFluentSyntax CreateColIfNotExists(this MigrationBase self, string tableName, string colName, Func<IAlterTableColumnAsTypeSyntax, IFluentSyntax> constructColFunction, string schemaName = "dbo")
        {
            if (!self.Schema.Schema(schemaName).Table(tableName).Column(colName).Exists())
            {
                return constructColFunction(self.Alter.Table(tableName).AddColumn(colName));
            }
            else
                return null;
        }`

Comment: Then call it like this: `this.CreateColIfNotExists("Table", "Col", col => col.AsInt32().Nullable().Indexed());`

Comment: Right, that's what I'm doing. I was just attempting to let future readers know that it was possible in case they (like me) found this question while looking for the ability to do this with columns.

Comment: I only wrote this because you wrote "There may be a better way to do this that doesn't involve duplicating the table declaration, but I couldn't figure it out", anyway 'ts all good.

Comment: Oh, I completely missed that part. That is way better, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: thanks all for this very great examples!